# Equality of GDI+ Regions

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, gdi

Why does the assertion fail in the following code? Why aren't regions `a` and `b` equal?

```
  Region a = new Region(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
  Region b = new Region();
  b.MakeEmpty();
  b.Union(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
  Debug.Assert(a == b, "Regions not equal");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, `System.Drawing.Region` does not override `Object`'s implementation of `Equals()`. Therefore your `==` call is using `ReferenceEquals` and simply telling you `a` and `b` are not the same object.

Try using the [`System.Drawing.Region.Equals(Region, Graphics)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yx605z9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload instead, passing in a `Graphics` object in the context you wish to compare the two regions.